# NullReferenceException at ServerRequestSecurityState.GetSecurityGroupsForCurrentUser(IWindowsIdentity identity)

Tags: iis-7.5, nullreferenceexception, windows-authentication, lightswitch-2013

I have deployed one Lightswitch application. Details are:

1. Used VS2013
2. Have HTML Client for application
3. Have desktop client deployed in web for role/users/permission management
4. Used windows authentication and allow access to only those mentioned in aspnet provider database(desktop client)
5. IIS7.5

I am getting some error when I access the page, it give be below error.

---

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web    request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.ServerRequestSecurityState.GetSecurityGroupsForCurrentUser(IWindowsIdentity identity) +56
   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsWindowsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal, ServerRequestSecurityState state) +373
   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal) +317
   Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.AuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context, HttpStatusCode& status, Exception& authException) +201
   Microsoft.LightSwitch.WebHost.Implementation.LightSwitchHttpModule.HandlePostAuthenticateRequest() +201
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +79
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +164

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

---

Following is the warning logged in event log.

---

```
+ System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 

  - EventID 1309 

   [ Qualifiers]  32768 

   Level 3 

   Task 3 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-08-01T15:03:43.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 107901 

   Channel Application 

   Computer <DELETED> 

   Security 


- EventData 

   3005 
   An unhandled exception has occurred. 
   8/1/2014 8:33:43 PM 
   8/1/2014 3:03:43 PM 
   e6e596e599ff4465968b9afeb7739958 
   183 
   58 
   0 
   /LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT-1-130513779129486922 
   Full 
   / 
   D:\PublishedWebsites\CustomerComplaints\ 
   <DELEED> 

   8976 
   w3wp.exe 
   IIS APPPOOL\CustomerComplaints 
   NullReferenceException 
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.ServerRequestSecurityState.GetSecurityGroupsForCurrentUser(IWindowsIdentity identity) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsWindowsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal, ServerRequestSecurityState state) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.AuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context, HttpStatusCode& status, Exception& authException) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.WebHost.Implementation.LightSwitchHttpModule.HandlePostAuthenticateRequest() at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  
   http://<CurrentMachine>:8451/CustomerComplaints/ 
   /CustomerComplaints/ 
   ::1 

   False 

   IIS APPPOOL\CustomerComplaints 
   34 
   IIS APPPOOL\CustomerComplaints 
   False 
   at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.ServerRequestSecurityState.GetSecurityGroupsForCurrentUser(IWindowsIdentity identity) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsWindowsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal, ServerRequestSecurityState state) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.IsUserRegistered(IPrincipal principal) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Utilities.Server.Internal.SecurityHelper.AuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context, HttpStatusCode& status, Exception& authException) at Microsoft.LightSwitch.WebHost.Implementation.LightSwitchHttpModule.HandlePostAuthenticateRequest() at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

---

I believe it is something wrong with my IIS settings, but not sure. I tried to search cause and solution but not getting any clue.

Comment: "I believe it is something wrong with IIS" - I think you'll find its a bug in YOUR code.

Comment: But it is not reaching to document.ready of default.htm itself. so msls._run() not yet called. It is no where reaching to my code so that i can debug.